# How to download only part of html page

Tags: android, xpath, download

How to download only part of html page in android?

Here is XPATH:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/section[1]/article
```

this part structure

```
<article class="post news" >
    <some content here>
</article>
```

Comment: If you just download the HTML you could try to process the information and return only this part, it's not what you are asking for but it's a fast solution

Comment: You can read the page symbol by symbol and stop reading after symbols stop matching your x-path expression. But it is much more complex than downloading a full page and only then applying x-path parser.

Answer (score 0):

will

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/section[1]/article[@class="post news"]
```

work?

Comment: Can you give me more information about how should I download it?